# Spring kstreams cannot get processor to work - The class '[B' is not in the trusted packages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

Full code: https://github.com/BenedictWHD/kstreams-example

So I have a producer (`data-ingest`), processor (`external-message-processor`), and consumer (`internal-message-processor` (This will become a processor later once I get things working, so apologies for the naming at the moment, but it is a consumer)).

The `data-ingest` works from what I can tell as it sends messages to the topic `external_messages`.

The `external-message-processor` attempts to read from that topic but fails with the following:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class '[B' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.yetti.common.externalmessage, com.yetti.common.externalmessage.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).`

Example of a message on the topic:

`Headers: __TypeId__: [B, contentType: application/json, spring_json_header_types: {"contentType":"java.lang.String"}"eyJpZCI6IjE4ZGQ2ODc4LWYwNWQtNDJiOC1iYTdlLTU2MDhmMTkzOWU3YyIsImV4dGVybmFsTWVzc2FnZVNvdXJjZSI6IlNNUyIsIm1lc3NhZ2VUeXBlIjoiVFJBTlNBQ1RJT04iLCJudW1iZXJGcm9tIjoiMSIsIm51bWJlclRvIjoiMiIsImNjeSI6Ik5UVEwiLCJxdWFudGl0eSI6IjIuNSJ9"`

As you can see the TypeId is for some reason "[B".

I have specified for all 3 of the applications to use the following serializer and deserializer:

```
          serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
          deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

Only the `data-ingest` one seems to actually be using the correct serializer as on the others when the application's startup in the producer and consumer configs we have this:

```
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

From what I can see in the application.yml files everything is as it should be so I am at a loss for why it is not using the serializer/deserializer I have specified and why the processor is unable to read the messages of the topic?

Any help much appreciated as I have been scratching my head on this for a couple of days now.

The repo at the start contains all the configuration files, poms and the docker-composer file to run this.

Edit - Processor Config:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  function:
    definition: processExternalMessage
  bindings:
    processExternalMessage-in-0:
      destination: external_messages
    processExternalMessage-out-0:
      destination: internal_messages
  kafka:
      bindings:
        processExternalMessage-out-0:
          producer:
            configuration:
              value:
                serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
        processExternalMessage-in-0:
          consumer:
            configuration:
              value:
                deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

Producer Config:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  function:
    definition: externalMessageProducer
  bindings:
    externalMessageProducer-out-0:
      destination: external_messages
  kafka:
      bindings:
        externalMessageProducer-out-0:
          producer:
            configuration:
              value:
                serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value.serializer` is a flat configuration property name. `value` is not a nested object with a `serializer` field, in YAML terms

That's why the other one seems to work

Also worth pointing out that [Kstreams uses `serde` properties, not serializers directly](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_inbound_deserialization)

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of what the config should look like? I will add what it currently is to the question

Comment: Like I said, `configuration:` (newline), `value.serializer: com.spring...`. You also shouldn't use both yaml and properties files as I believe only one gets read

Comment: Ahh got you,

Should be:

`configuration:
              value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer`

Instead of 

`configuration:
              value:
                serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer`

Comment: So all I should need to do now is implement the Serde<ExternalMessage> method?

Comment: In fact, I don't suppose you know of a great example for kstreams that is not just using boxed primitives for the data being sent between topics and being processed?

Comment: I typically stay between JSON or AVRO since those are the most supported. I think I've only ever made my own serde a handful of times

Comment: Perfect, I am currently trying to get it to work with AVRO! Thanks for the help and advice